# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Status"

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am receiving following error message, I have Status class but it is not being recognized. I've got no idea how to proceed and could not find an answer online.

**Error**

```
   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could 
   not read JSON: Unrecognized field "Status" (class 
   com.myproject.ticket.EventsResponse), not marked as ignorable (3 known 
   properties: "events", "status", "page"])
      ....
   Caused by: 
   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
   Unrecognized field "Status" (class com.myproject.ticket.EventsResponse), 
   not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "events", "status", "page"])
```

**EventsResponse**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "Status")
    private Status status;
    @XmlElement(name = "Paging")
    private Page page;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Events")
    @XmlElement(name = "Event")
    private List<Event> events;

    .....
```

**Status**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Status {
    @XmlElement(name = "Version")
    private double version;
    @XmlElement(name = "TimeStampUtc")
    private Date timeStampUtc;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private int code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Message")
    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "Details")
    private String details;
```

**Response**

```
<EventsResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Status>
        <Version>2.0</Version>
        <TimeStampUtc>2016-06-11T09:32:21</TimeStampUtc>
        <Code>0</Code>
        <Message>Success</Message>
        <Details />
    </Status>
    <Paging>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <PageSize>50</PageSize>
        <PageResultCount>15</PageResultCount>
        <TotalResultCount>15</TotalResultCount>
        <TotalPageCount>1</TotalPageCount>
    </Paging>
    <Events>
        <Event>
```

I added following to Status but I am still receiving the same error.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Status")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Status")
private Status status;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your XML?

Comment: @MattPearce yes just included in question.

Comment: can you provide the entire stacktrace

Comment: @Haim I updated the question thanks.

Comment: can you specify spring version in use?

Comment: @Haim version of my Spring is 3.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below?

Comment: @Haim it seems thats not what I am looking for. I am confused that it recognizes all elements except Status. If I am to access different webservices wont be able to fix specific formats for data fields like date.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the use case? The 3.2.8 version was critical information. Can you share a sample project with the exception

Comment: @Haim what do you mean by sample project with the exception? I do not have Git account. I am puzzled with the issue not sure why other classes are being recognized except this one.

Answer (score 3):

I failed to reconstruct your issue.

I created a test project [github here](https://github.com/ramanh3/q37721564) that has Jackson configuration and JAXB annotations that meet your needs.

I added dependencies to jackson-dataformat-xml and woodstox-core-asl as your Stax implementations (in my test project I am using Jackson 2.6.6. ,Spring 4.2.6)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to use both Jackson and JAXB annotations. This is a Spring-boot example to convert to Simple Spring-MVC look [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EventAppConfiguration {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(EventAppConfiguration.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
      Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
      b.indentOutput(true)
      //Enable Introspects for both Jackson and JAXB annotation
     .annotationIntrospector(introspector())
      //Use CamelCase naming
     .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE)
     .dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"));
      return b;
  }
  @Bean
  public AnnotationIntrospector introspector(){
     AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
     AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new    JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
     AnnotationIntrospector pair =  AnnotationIntrospector.pair(primary, secondary);
    return pair;
 }
}
```

Note the use of

```
PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE
```

it will save you the need to specify alternative naming for first letter capitalization and will require the use for JAXB annotation only for warping and  renaming for example my EventsResponse will look like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EventsResponse {
       private Status status;
       @XmlElement(name = "Paging")
       private Page page;
       @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Events")
       @XmlElement(name = "Event")
       private List<Event> events;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, assuming you are using Jackson to deserialize your XML objects. The simplest is to use Jackson's own XML annotations instead of or as well as the JAXB `@XmlElement` annotations. For example:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Status")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Status")
private Status status;
```

(The `@XmlElement` annotation is in the `jackson-dataformat-xml` package in Maven - the version should match your other Jackson package versions.)

The alternative is to register an AnnotationIntrospector as part of your deserialization chain - ie. (from a unit test):

```
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    AnnotationIntrospector aiJaxb = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(aiJaxb);
    // EVENTS_RESPONSE is the incoming XML
    EventsResponse response = mapper.readValue(EVENTS_RESPONSE, EventsResponse.class);
```

This recognises the `@XmlElement` annotation. There are more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601370/jackson-unable-to-consider-xmlelement-while-serializing-to-json) if you need to include this as part of a Spring configuration, for example.

(In order to use the `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` class, you will need the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotation` module from Maven.)

Comment: thanks, I added the annotation you suggested but it seems I am using a different depenency to what you use. As the IDE says jacksonXmlProperty cannot be resolved to a type. Why does it my code recognize Status? why should I use JacksonXmlProperty?

Comment: I've added some notes on the dependencies needed. Jackson 2.x doesn't support the default JAXB annotations out of the box - see their wiki page (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) for more details.

Comment: I followed your first solution but the code still returns following error. org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "Status" (class com.myproject.ticket.EventsResponse), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "events", "status", "page"])   Question is updated.

Comment: I think, since you're using Spring, the second suggestion is more appropriate. In particular, adding the annotations from the linked answer should help (I don't use Spring, so can't verify that those annotations do what is needed - as such, I don't want to include them in my answer).

Comment: you'll have to register the jaxbannotationmodule in your object mapper using modules to install feature in jackson2objectmapperfactorbean to have jackson recognise jaxb annotations.